# How to get the data from the First Row using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in vm.model.pairingFilesWithStatus" ng-class="{'file-deleted': file.isDeleted}" class="">
<td>04</td>
<td>2021</td>
<td>Pairing</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="file in vm.model.pairingFilesWithStatus" ng-class="{'file-deleted': file.isDeleted}" class=""> 
<td>11</td>
<td>2020</td>
<td>Pairing</td>
```

My script:

```
  element(by.tagName('td')).getAttribute('innerText').each(function (item) {
    item.getText().then(function (Result) {
      console.log(Result);
    });
  });
```

Output: Getting data from all rows

i wanted to get the data from only first Row. can anyone please share code.

Comment: WHy are you getting innertext again using each?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need each as you are using element() and not element.all()

```
  element(by.tagName('td')).getAttribute('innerText').then(function (Result) {
      console.log(Result);
    });
  });
```

or you can also use:

```
  element.all(by.css('td')).then(function(items) {
      expect(items.length).toBe(3);
      expect(items[0].getText()).toBe('First');
  });
```

or

```
  let first = element.all(by.css('.items li')).first();
  expect(first.getText()).toBe('First');
```

**Also i recomment to use await instead of this complicated chaining stuff**

Answer (score 0):

```
element.all(by.css('tr[ng-repeat="file in vm.model.pairingFilesWithStatus"]'))
 .first() // get the first row
 .all('by.css("td")') // get all td of first row
 .getText() // get text of all td of first row
```